# Trouble with sed

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to write a program that will make some incremental updates for me.  I was trying to use sed like this:

```
while read line
do
  sed -i 's?$line?$line:$(stat -c %y $line)?g' tmp_file
  myarry[$count]=$line
done < "tmp_file"
```

I added some text to this "tmp_file" and cleaned it up then I was going to read all the lines into an array and check it against another file.  if the modification time (%y) had changed, it was going to make a .tar backup of the file incase something broke further down the road.

I am having some trouble getting it to read my line.  Or maybe the problem is the changing of the line?  Or the array? Either way, its not giving me the desired result, i.e an entry in my array with the lines info.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Variables/etc. don't expand in single quotes. And you need to be careful to escape strings used in sed patterns/etc.

Comment: Thanks.  I could have sworn that I tried that, but as soon as I double quoted it worked for me.  Thanks!